# Why is there no 'notEqual' method in Joiners class?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm using the Joiners class to make a Constraint.  The Joiners class has methods like equal(), greaterThan(), lessThanOrEqual(), etc.  I want to use a method such as "notEqual()" because I want to compare two objects of the same class, and assign a penalty if the value for a property is not the same.  Please note that I use Joiners.lessThan(..id..) to ensure that I am comparing pairs of objects without doing it twice.  This is an example of code I'd like to be able to write:

```
private Constraint someConflict(ConstraintFactory cf) {
    return cf.from(A.class)
        .join(A.class, // Pair the above A with this A
            Joiners.notEqual(A::getSomething), // ..if they have differing Something
            Joiners.lessThan(A::getId)) // ..and if the pair is unique (no reverse pairs)
        .penalizeConfigurable();
}
```

The "notEqual" will fail as it doesn't exist, obviously.  Is there a way to do this?  It seems logical that this kind of operation should be possible.  If not, could I please be enlightened?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Good question!

The `Joiners` methods `equal()`, `greaterThan()`, `lessThanOrEqual()`, etc use an index (= hash table). This means they are a lot faster for large dataset than without such an index. See the 2 images below. (This independent from the "incremental" aspect of scoring.)

We are not sure yet if it's a good idea to use an index for `notEquals()`. At the same time, we want to give the guarantee that all Joiners methods are using an index, except for `filtering`. So no `notEquals(Bar::getFoo)` if it's not indexed. Right now `filtering((a, b) -> !a.getFoo().equals(b.getFoo()))` works. Maybe we should add `notEqualsFiltering(Bar::getFoo)` as syntactic sugar?

[image: slow]

[image]

Comment: Deeper discussion: https://kie.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/232679-optaplanner/topic/CS.20Joiners.2EnotEquals()

Comment: Geoffrey, I would certainly vote for this -> "Maybe we should add notEqualsFiltering(Bar::getFoo) as syntactic sugar?"